# Can't change a dupe vote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, duplicate-questions

I voted to close a question as dupe [Given GPS coordinates in decimals, how can I convert them to degrees in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723781/given-gps-coordinates-in-decimals-how-can-i-convert-them-to-degrees-in-python)

The dupe I found had the answer in C# so it wasn't quite a dupe and poster commented asking 
for an answer in python.

I then found an exact dupe, in python, - but I can't vote to close again and I can't edit my dupe link in the autogenerated comment because the edit window had passed.

Should dupe comments be editable for longer? Or should there be a mechanism to change a close vote?

Comment: For now, this is by design, but we might revisit when looking at duplicate handling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete the auto generated comment and then leave a new comment explaining that you've found the real duplicate - include the link to that.

Then, hopefully, the next person to come along will pick your the new link as the duplicate. Other than flagging for a moderator there's not a lot else you can do.

I've just gone and done used your new question as a duplicate now.

Comment: Yes that's what I did - didn't know if that's the 'official' fix

Comment: @MartinBeckett It's the only thing you can so, since you cannot change the vote you have already casted.